# content matching in iframe

Tags: rspec, capybara

Here is the scenario, i'd like to check a iframe on my page to make sure certain content exists. and i tried:

```
within_frame 'my_frame_name' do 
  find('#id_of_a_div').value should match 'match me please' 
end
```

tried a couple of variations, none worked.

any suggestions?

Comment: great question! anybody?

Comment: Could you give more details? Exact code you used? Exceptions thrown? Variations you tried?

Comment: I think OP's issue was because there was no dot between `value` and `should`.

Answer (score 0):

```
within_frame 'my_frame_name' do 
  find('#id_of_a_div').value.should == 'match me please' 
end
```